# Spring Core Course solution exercises not working anymore

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-3

Last year i did the core course from Spring. At that course i received a very good book named "Core Spring Student lecture manual" + exercises book. The problem is that after houres of suffering i still not managed to get the examples(solutions) runnable.

I have two options: 
-First i tryed to import all the projects into STS and intellij and i try to build them with Maven.

I also added all the dependency's manualy to my local repostirory but i get two errors

This repository does not exist anymore:
Code:

```
<url>https://tbits.springsource.com/repository/snapshot</url>
```

and when i remove that repository in the pom.xml maven it complained that he can't find the parent project.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.springsource.training.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>abstractContainerProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

-As second i tryed to remove all the maven part and i just added the library's one by one manually to the projects the code compiles fine than but the problem is that the unit tests are nut running i get a stack trace "java.lang.exception" no runnable methods found.

For me i doesn't mather if it works with maven or manually as long as i can run the tests / compile its ok.

Is there anyone who also had problem with this?

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you're not supposed to import them to any local IDE, you're supposed to use the STS provided in the material. Same goes to the repository - repository is provided in the training material. That's the same thing they've [adviced in the spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81912-Newbie-Question-on-Spring-and-the-Training-Class-Examples) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have installed course from Spring, go to the directory where it is installed. There is a folder called repository. For e.g on mac /Applications/core-spring-3.2.1.RELEASE/repository.

Here you will find all dependencies which you can then add to the classpath manually (add external jar).

Or in case of maven: just copy the whole folder ...repository/com/springsource into .m2 folder.